# Finding the Constant Term of a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

How the coefficient of $t^{m+q}$ in the product $g'h'$ is

$$g_0h_{m+q}+g_1h_{m+q-1}+ \cdots +g_mh_q+\cdots g_{m+q}h_0 ?$$

For example, if $g_2=x^2+1, h_3=x^3+x^2+1$, then what is the value of $g_0h_{m+q}$? Plz explain reason in general for other terms.

The source of the problem -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide the value of $m+q$.  The given expression sums up the different ways to get the exponent of $t$ to be $m+q$.  The first term comes from multiplying the constant term in $g$, which is $g_0$ by the $t^{m+q}$ term in $h$.  The second comes from multiplying the linear term in $g$, which is $g_1t$ by the corresponding term in $h$, which is $h_{m+q-1}t^{m+q-1}$ and so on.

In your example, $g_0=1, g_1=0, g_2=1, h_0=1,h_2=1,h_3=1$

Comment: " the first term comes from multiplying the constant term in $g$, which is $g_0$ by the $t^{m+q}$ term in $h$"....You are missing a point , by definition $h$ does not have a term  $t^{m+q}$ , by definition the  degree of $h$ is $\leq m$.

Comment: I don't see that the degree of $h$ is $\le m$ in the portion you quoted.  If so, that term is $0$, as are all the ones until $g_q$  In the example, if you asked for the $x^5$ term in $gh$ the first equation would have $5$ terms.  The only one that would be nonzero would be $g_2h_3$.

Comment: See the last 2 paragraph in the image,  from "we can choose the first of each set of coefficient, say $g_m, h_q$..."

Comment: That looks to me just a term that is not divisible by $k$.  It says nothing about the degree of $g,h$.  The given expression assumes that both $g,h$ are at least of degree $m+q$  It just comes from general polynomial multiplication.

Comment: What is the meaning of  "we can choose the first of each set of coefficient" in the proof , could u plz rephrase?

Comment: He is looking for the lowest order term in each polynomial where the coefficient is not divisible by $k$.  If $g(x)=x^3+3x^2+2x+4$ and $k=2$ it would be $g_2=3$ because $2,4$ are both divisible by $2$.  If the one from $h$ were $h_1$ we would be looking at the $x^3$ terms in the product and only $g_2h_1$ would be odd.